# Getting "Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy" error when trying to make a POST request from localhost to remote server

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I am trying to make a POST request from my localhost to a remote server and I am getting the error "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://chat-app-main-server.vercel.app/api/auth/login' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy." The strange thing is that the code works fine when I run it locally, but it fails when I try to run it on a remote server.

I have tried adding the following headers to my request, but it doesn't seem to help.:

[issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSK8w.png)

I am not sure what else to try. How can I troubleshoot this issue and fix it?

Comment: Have you setup CORS on your express server?

Docs: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: Yes I've installed cors. and set up it in app.js file: app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5173',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'PUT'],
    credentials: true
}))

Answer (score -1):

Please install `CORS` npm or yarn package in nodejs(Backend)

If you use your local server then use like:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const env = require('dotenv');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const userRoute = require('./routers/users')
const cors = require('cors')
 
env.config()

require('./dbConn/dbConn')

const corsOptions = ["http://localhost:3000/"] // (You can ur server also)
app.use(cors(corsOptions)
```